# Database Incrementing Not Working Correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to have the ID increase automatically in my table but I'm confused on why it worked up until 2 and then went straight to 5. I checked my error list but I'm not getting any errors. I also made sure that I increment by only 1. I checked out a few questions about auto increment on stack and wasn't able to find what I'm missing. Is this not the correct way to increment in my database? (I'm using Visual Studio)

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8XOM.png)

[Data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tRfn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Despite its name, a MySQL `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is not supposed to be serial, but only *different* each time. Don't expect consecutive numbers.

Your toold defines an `IDENTITY` column, but that doesn't exist in MySQL (yet).

But... why would you even care in the first place? It's for a primary key that needs to be unique, and where the specific value is unimportant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, I thought it usually goes in order. Is there a way to make it go in order? It's just a preference, if there is a way to make it go in order I'd like them to be. @TheImpaler

Comment: It's a primary key. Primary keys are not supposed to be sexy or good looking. They are only supposed to be UNIQUE, and are not suitable to be exposed to the outside world. If you care about the number, then you probably want to show it somewhere. That's a no-no.